# getting model belongsTo attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
class Batch extends Eloquent {
    public function coupons() {
        return $this->hasMany('Coupon');
    }
}

class Coupon extends Eloquent {
    public function batch() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Batch');
    }
    public function price() {
        $batch = $this->batch;
        return $batch->price;
    }
}
```

`$coupon->price` gives me this error:-

> LogicException Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

However, `$coupon->batch->price` works just fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue here is that you define a non-relationship method `price()` but you call it as if it was a relationship method (i.e. you call it as a property and not as a method).

The code you should be using to get the `Coupon`'s price is:

```
$coupon->price();
```

The reason the relationship thing works (i.e. `$coupon->batch` over `$coupon->batch()`) is that Laravel has some special logic in - basically it catches you trying to access a property (`->batch` in this case) and checked to see if there's a corresponding method (`->batch()`). If there is one, it calls it and expects it to return a relationship, and then it calls `->first()` of `->get()` on that relationship depending on whether it's a single-result or a multiple-result relationship.

So what's happening in your code here is that you call `$coupon->price` and Laravel, behind the scenes, decides that being as there's a `->price()` method it must be a relationship. It calls the method, checks that it returns one of the Laravel relationship types, and when it doesn't, throws that `LogicException`.

The general rules of thumb is this:

- If you want an actual property (i.e. anything defined on the table) or the results of a relationship query, use property access
- If you want anything else (i.e. behaviour you're defined using a method) you must call the method directly

Also, sometimes there is a good reason to call a relationship as the method rather than the property - calling the method returns something you can add query builder constraints on to, whereas calling the property gets you all the results. So say `Coupon`s can be enabled or disabled (for example), the following holds:

- `$batch->coupons` gets you all coupons that the batch has
- `$batch->coupons()->whereEnabled(1)->get()` gets you all enabled coupons for a given batch
- `$batch->coupons()->orderBy('order')->get()` gets you all the coupons that the batch has, ordered by a field called `order`
- `$coupon->batch` gets you the given coupon's batch

Hopefully that explains the difference between Eloquent's use of methods versus properties for relationships, and why all augmented behaviour (like price on coupon in your example, but *not* price on batch, which is inherent behaviour) must be called as a method.

Comment: thanks for the excellent explanation of the laravel magic. I assumed there was something like that happening behind the scenes, but I couldn't quite pin it down

Comment: Yeah it's something that's not really documented. The collection versus query builder is mentioned in the Eloquent relationships docs, but not the fact that it can't be used for *other* things. Glad to be of help, anyway.

Comment: I think you have a typo: `->first()` **or** `->get()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment to realize what objects you actually have here.

When you call `$this->batch;` you're no longer chaining the relationship queries - you've actually retrieved the information from the database already. In order to define that query you'd have to do it one of several ways including:

```
Coupon::with('batch.price')->get();
```

You could of course do it with relationships but it's late and I'm not sure where exactly Price belongs in the scheme of this since I don't see a method for it associated with batch. Presumably you could do:

```
public function price()
{
    return $this->batch->price;
}
```

if Price is a derivative of Batch.

Comment: strangely enough, $this->batch->price also didnt work. I did try that option along the way. I think @alexrussel has nailed it